# VB.NET talking with Microsoft Access - can one do callbacks?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, callback, vba

I'm building an add-on UI system in VB.NET (Visual Basic specifically) that uses data from a legacy Microsoft Access system (that will at least for some time needs to be useful via its old, internal UI).  I can do pretty much everything I need to do from VB.net - work with the data tables, call Access functions that contain decent functionality, etc.

What I'm trying to figure out is if Microsoft Access can call *back* to VB.NET (e.g., perhaps allowing me to pass in a function reference to be invoked).

The specific motivation is that there are 2 or 3 time-consuming Microsoft Access functions that produce critical output data - if you were invoking them directly via the MS Access interface, you would see things like progress bars and the occasional text update on a form of the work phase, progress %, etc.  I can modify the MS Access code not to do these things if called from VB.net, but I'd *really* rather have the MS Access code reach back into VB.net so that I can provide some progress feedback in the new interface.

An elegant solution would be, as alluded to above, have VB.NET pass in the function delegate for MS Access to call - but as these are entirely different memory spaces, etc., I would think some internal framework would be required to get such a thing to work - perhaps via a shared DLL in some manner.   I could go the old "polling" route, wherein MS Access writes out status to a table, and the (asynchronous) VB.NET app polls that table and uses what's there.  That seems like such an inelegant hack, unnecessarily wasteful in resources and potentially bug prone, that I hate to go that route.  If I could build just one function that MS Access could use, something that just passes a status string back, I think that'd cover the vast majority of cases.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often create COM objects in .net for use with Access. Thus in your access code you could MOST certainly have the process loop “call” the .net object to update the process.

However, you likely are automating a copy of Access, and thus would like Access to call a routine in the EXISTING automation client, not have an instance of Access call a custom .net object. However, I think building a custom .net object would be the least work and hassle. In other words, you flip your approach around. You launch Access first and it uses your .net application as a COM object. That way, any routine in your application would be useable and callable from Access VBA.

The ONLY reason why I would walk down the road of implementing a call back if the main .net app REALLY needs to receive messages from Access as opposed to Access simply calling + using a custom .net object to display the process information. (so VERY easy to build a .net object for showing progress).

So best bet is to adopt the idea of turning your existing application into a COM object to be consumed by Access. This is VERY easy.

Once you do above, then

Access is launched first and then creates the instance of your application. (and thus can call/use any .net sub or function expose in your .net application from VBA).

And even if you don’t launch Access first, Access on startup could grab a running instance of your application (just like you can pick up a running instance of Excel or Word in Access/VBA).

Last but not least;
You probably can implement call backs, but I simply don’t know if this is possible without having to create a .net COM object as a go-between. As such, likely best to have Access just pick up a running instance of your .net application anyway.

So I would expose your .net application as a COM instable object.

So least amount of work would be to create a separate .net COM object that access uses, but if you assume for future that VBA should be able to call any vb.net routine then I would thus just build your .net application as a consumable COM object.